# C interface to Erlang

Tags: c, interop, erlang

When i compile example of interoperation between C and erlang with next command:

> gcc -o fac -I/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.5.9/include \
>   -L/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.5.9/lib fac.c -lerl_interface -lei

My system is Ubuntu. I got next errors:

> /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `__erl_errno_place':
>   (.text+0x4c): undefined reference to`pthread_once'
>   /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `__erl_errno_place':
>   (.text+0x7a): undefined reference to`pthread_getspecific'
>   /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `__erl_errno_place':
>   (.text+0xa2): undefined reference to`pthread_setspecific'
>   /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `__erl_errno_place':
>   (.text+0xb4): undefined reference to`pthread_getspecific'
>   /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `erl_errno_key_alloc':
>   (.text+0x136): undefined reference to`pthread_key_create'
>   /usr/lib/libei.a(ei_pthreads.o): In function `ei_m_trylock':
>   (.text+0x189): undefined reference to`pthread_mutex_trylock'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link `pthread` library. Try:
`gcc -o fac -I/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.5.9/include  -L/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.5.9/lib fac.c -lerl_interface -lei -lpthread`
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Please try if specifying the command line option `-pthread` (or if something has changed `-lpthread`) solves the problem.

Comment: voted up for both answers, but accept second because it more precise. Thanks much.